# Move a Sharepoint Server 2010 Web Application to Sharepoint Foundation 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

What are the options when having to migrate a Web Application / Site Collection from Sharepoint Server to Sharepoint Foundation please?

I know that SharePoint complains if the version does not match exactly during a backup and restore ... but is there any way to achieve this please?

Thanks

Joseph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your steps should be:

1. Take backup of Server Content Database
2. Restore on SQL server for Server test environment
3. Take backup from server test environment
4. Restore on SQL server for Foundation
5. Run Test-SPContentDatabase on Foundation
6. If any problems remove problems on Server test environment and go to 3
7. Attach database to Foundation

Comment: You should also be sure that you are not using features that are only on the server edition. Some of these are not as easily discovered. I had this issue so thought I would share.

Comment: Step 5 should report these